# How to get rid of automatic fill in html?

Tags: html, web-development-server, visual-web-developer

i want to get rid of the auto fill in

i am new to html and i cant ix my problem. if you dont understand me ill be more than happy to send a screenshot using gmail.

```
<FORM action="Database.php" method="GET">
<LABEL>First Name</LABEL>
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<br>
```

Last Name

Comment: just use `autocomplete="off"` in your tag like this `<input type="text" name="firstName" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: I’m still new to stack overflow idk how to do that

Comment: just go to my answer there will be tick option just select that tick

Answer (score 1):

just use `autocomplete="off"` in your tag like this

`<input type="text" name="firstName" autocomplete="off">`

to know more visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: The `autocomplete` attribute has been ignored by browsers for years.